# Set value of radio button based on PHP code

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have multiple radio buttons that are linked together. I want to set the value of each radio button based on whether it is clicked/set or not

**Edit** I have included the full code for one set of radio buttons. A set since they are all called the same name. 
    
>

```
<td><br><input type="radio" name="meal1" <?php if (isset($meal2)){
    echo "checked", "value = '1'";
 } else {
    echo "value = '0'";
 }
 ?>>
</td>

<td><br><input type="radio" name="meal1" <?php if (isset($meal3)){
    echo "checked", "value = '1'";
} else {
    echo "value = '0'";
}
;?>>
</td>

<td><br><input type="radio" name="meal1" <?php if (isset($meal4)){
    echo "checked", "value = '1'";
} else {
    echo "value = '0'";
}
;?>>
</td>
```

**Edit** This code is now changed from previous one just to echo the output of each

```
if(isset($_POST['order'])){
if(!isset($_POST['meal1'])){
    echo "Radio buttons not set.";
} else {
$meal1 = $_POST['meal1'];
$meal2 = $_POST['meal1'];
$meal3 = $_POST['meal1'];
$meal4 = $_POST['meal1'];

print_r($meal1);
print_r($meal2);
print_r($meal3);
print_r($meal4);
}
```

When I execute the code below, after clicking on of the radio buttons. The output is 0,0,0,0. I would like the output to 1,0,0,0 Since I have clicked the first radio button.

Comment: Well I don't see in the code you posted where you're setting the value of $_POST['meal1'].

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
 echo "checked"; "value = '1'";
```

Does nothing. You stop the echo command half way through.

```
echo "checked value='1'";
```

should do the trick.